# prove that this complex function is the zero function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

we know that $f$ is analytic in the ring $R=$ {$z: r_1 < |z| < r_2$}. moreover at the circle {$z:|z|=r_2$} $f$ is continuous and for every $z$ in that circle $f(z) = 0$ .

We have to prove that $f(z)=0$ for every $z \in R$

Comment: What do you mean by "contentious "?

Comment: continuous. spelling error. now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Schwarz's reflection principle $f$ can be analytically extended to $r_1<|z|<\frac{{r_2}^2}{r_1}$. Next by the coincidence theorem it follows that $f(z)=0$ for every $z\in R$.

Comment: what if $r_2 < 1$ ?

Comment: Even if $r_2<1$, $r_1<r_2<\frac{{r_2}^2}{r_1}$. Therefore $r_1<|z|<r_2$ is contained in $r_1<|z|<\frac{{r_2}^2}{r_1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Comment: I guessed I should use them, but how ...? note the the circle $|z| = r_2$ is not the entire boundary of $R$ . in the boundary you also have the circle $|z|=r_1$

Answer (score 0):

You could use Cauchy's integral formula for an annulus. Pick $r_1<\alpha<\beta<r_2$, then for every $\alpha<|z|<\beta$, we have $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|t|=\beta} \frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt-\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|t|=\alpha} \frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt.$$ Since this formula holds for all $\beta$ ($\alpha<\beta<r_2$), then by continuity, for every $\alpha<|z|<r_2$, we have $$f(z)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|t|=\alpha} \frac{f(t)}{t-z}dt.$$ But the right hand side is a Cauchy type integral, i.e. the right hand side is analytic for all $z$, $\alpha<|z|<\infty$. Thus, $f(z)$ is analytic on $\alpha<|z|<\infty$ and so by uniqueness, $f(z)=0$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$.